# What to consider when chooing weightings for bank account modulus checks

Tags: coding-theory

UK bank accounts and sort codes are validated using a couple of rules, including modulus 10 and modulus 11. The details on how this works are given here: https://www.vocalink.com/customer-support/modulus-checking/

I understand the reason for these checks are to catch common keying errors when bank account numbers are entered. I'm assuming different variations of the validation rules catch different numbers or classes of keying mistakes.

Each sort code has a set of sort and account digit weightings that are used in the calculations. They are listed here: https://www.vocalink.com/media/3036/valacdos.txt

The question is, what considerations are there when these weighting numbers are chosen?

- Are some better than others, or do some perform better in specific circumstances?
- If a zero is used as a weight, does that take a digit of the bank account (or sort code) out of the validation check, increasing the range of possible valid account numbers?
- If I were tasked to create a set of weights for a new sort code, how would I go about doing that.
- Would it make sense to try to use a different set of weightings to other banks to lower the number of bank account numbers that overlap with other banks? (That may be more a policy decision, but is that what it would effectively do?)

There are patterns in the weightings table linked above, but none seem to be used more than any other, so none seem to win out as "the best".

---

I'm hoping this is considered a mathematics question. I have no idea where the answer lies between "just throw a die" and "here are good mathematical reasons to choose certain numbers". I have a feeling the answer may be in this paper http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S2179-84512017000100105 but as a non-mathematician, this is pretty dense reading to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there's no inherent reason why different sort codes should have different weights or different moduli. That's just a historical accident -- at the time banks introduced computer systems (such that having check digits became relevant and feasible) different banks decided how their check digits would work separately and happened to come up with different schemes. By the time it was recognized it would have been a good idea to use the same kind of checksum everywhere, it was too late -- millions of customers had already been issued account numbers that validated differently between different banks.

If you're designing a check digit system from scratch you can ignore much of the complexity in the document you link to; it is only there to cope with historical accidents.

Down to the actual weights: The most important features to have are

- No digit position that you want any validation for can have weight $0$ -- that would mean that mistyping a digit in that position would never get caught. But as long as every weight is coprime to the modulus, all *single-digit* mistypes will get caught.
- Two *neighboring* weights should be different; otherwise a mistype where you swap two neighboring digits cannot be caught by the modulus check.

Beyond this, it is mostly a matter of arbitrary choice. Checks where the weights alternate between just two values can never catch errors where you interchange `abcd` to `cdab`, which is rather undesirable. But they are *slightly* faster to check than codes with all-different weights, which mattered back in the 1960s. On the other hand, you can't catch *all* abcd-to-cdab errors with a single check digit, so it's a trade-off.

The larger the modulus, the fewer digit strings will be valid account numbers. It should be at least 10, of course -- otherwise there's again a risk that single-digit errors will not get caught.

Modulus-10 has trouble, though: Since the weights need to be coprime to the modulus there are only 4 different weights that work with 10 (namely $1$, $3$, $7$, $9$). And that again means that some neighbor transpositons cannot be caught -- e.g. `38` to `83` cannot be caught with modulus-10 for any combinations of 1, 3, 7, 9 as weights.

This is why modulus-11 is popular: any difference between non-equal digits, as well as any difference between non-equal weights will be invertible modulo 11, so one can guarantee catching all neighbor transpositions. The cost is that not all sequences of $n-1$ digits have a valid check digit.

Overlap of the valid account number ranges between sort codes is not really a relevant problem -- the totality of *all* valid numbers for a sort code is not really what matters in practice. What arguably matters a bit in practice is the risk that a *single* given account number from a different bank is also valid at yours -- but with one check digit, that risk is going to average out to $1/10$ no matter how you might scramble the *entire* account number population by sort code.

Comment: Thanks, very useful and informative. We are using mod 11, so all weights below 11 will be coprime. We havea number of sequential sort codes, so would like weightings for those. Many banks use a weighting of `7 6 5 4 3 2` for the sort code and `7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0` for the account, meating the second requirement, but not for the last digit (giving them more account numbers to play with?). A variation uses `N 7 6 5 4 3 2 1` for the account, where N is any digit 1..9. Another popular pattern (now I am looking again) alternates `1 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...`. I'm guessing any of these are as good as any other?

Comment: @Jason: I don't know what's up with the 7-6-5-4-3-2-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-0 patterns. My best guess is that they're for validating 7-digit account numbers that later had a digit added to the end when the bank found itself running out of number space and had to move to 8-digit numbers. (Note that most of these cases have an alternative check covering the same sort-code range).

Comment: @Jason: (...) The "1-2-1-2..." patterns all seem to be for the "double alternate" summing method, which is quite bad -- it can never detect a swap between `90` and `09` no matter what the weights.

Comment: (Hmm, I misread the flowchart. When there are two checks for the same range, _both_ needs to match except if there's an exception code. So almost all of the 76543276543210 cases are ones where the 13th digit is produced from the first 12 by modulo-11, after which the 14th digit is computed from digits 1-13 by the "double alternate" method. (And these are _almost_ the only uses of DblAl)).

Comment: Goodness - sort code ranges listed multiple times with different weights. I feel dumb not seeing that. `902398` to `909999` is an interesting one - one rule for the sort code, then a separate rule for the account number. I guess that means the sort code can be validated against keying errors (only ~10% of the codes in that range will be valid), but the same account numbers will be valid for the full range of valid sort codes. I understand a lot more now (thank you) but I wish I felt closer to a solution (a set of weightings, with possibly one, possibly two rules).

Comment: @Jason: It is not clear to me which problem you're trying to solve. If you want to design a new checksum scheme that doesn't need to be compatible with anything in particular, I would just use mod11 with a plain descending sequence of weights.

Comment: Thank you. My problem is that I needed to create some weightings for a mod11 check on a new sort code. My hope was that there would be some simple compromises I needed to weight up in choosing the weightings, and my question was aimed at finding out what those compromises are. But it ain't so simple and there appear to be lots of answers that would work. If the descending weightings are as good as any, we will just go for that; other banks have done that: `6 5 4 3 2 1` and `8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1`. Thank you for your help - all much appreciated, and it helps us understand this in a lot more depth.